# Can I rename AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android

I create different android project in eclipse, but every project include the same name AndroidManifest.xml, can I rename AndroidManifest.xml? Thanks!

Comment: you talk about import problem ?

Comment: If you can explain why you senario to rename the file. May be we can find you an alternative solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`No`..manifest file work as bridge between your `Application` and the Android os.so It must be with same name.if you rename Android os doesnt know about your `Application`..

Answer (score 4):

**A big NO** and why you want to change name ?

**UPDATE**

Every application must have an [`AndroidManifest.xml`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) file in its root directory. 
The manifest file presents essential information about your app to the Android system, information the system must have before it can run any of the app's code.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't rename this. For more information you can read this topic:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot rename it, the reason behind this is that it has been used by the android OS, to know the Permissions, as well as to know which activity should be opened at what time. All such controls are written in this AndroidManifest file. So changing its name is not allowed.